# JavaScript-Facebook-integration: window.fbAsyncInit no longer firing

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbconnect

We use the fbAsnycInit hook to init the FB object, which was working till last week.
Now the hook does not get called any longer. 
There are no JS errors in the FireBug-Console in FF and the IEs Development tools. The hook is assigned correctly (according to debug output.)

```
before UnityObject
before embedUnity
after embedUnity
window.fbAsyncInit will be assigned: [object Window] window.fbAsyncInit: undefined
window.fbAsyncInit has been assigned: [object Window] window.fbAsyncInit: function () { log("fbAsyncInit"); FB.init({appId: "143585412381528", status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true}); log("FB.init finished"); FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {if (response.session) {log("User already logged in");}

window.fbAsyncInit has been assigned 2
load all.js started
load all.js finished        
firstFrameCallback
before send message[object HTMLEmbedElement] uid undefined
after send message
```

Do you have any ideas how to go on finding the cause? Are there some JS errors swallowed? The all.js library with problems?

The appliation can be found [here](http://apps.facebook.com/buildville).

UPDATE March, 8th 2012: At the moment the application seeems to work. Problems may be related to older revisions of Facebook supplied JS-files?!

Comment: When I try to open the app, I get an error regarding infinite redirection.

Comment: This works for me (in FF and Chrome), but I had it months ago, too ... Clearing the cache helped ... Thank you for trying! --Heinrich

Comment: I just tried again and was able to open the page. An authentification dialog was displayed that requested the permissions you specified in the code. So window.fbAsyncInit does fire. Maybe a temporary problem with Facebook? Anyway, I don't see any output except for a install Unity Player plugin. The function that adjusts the content of the session div does not work. That part needs to be moved inside the window.fbAsyncInit call, too.

Comment: Output IE9:
`LOG: before UnityObject 
LOG: before embedUnity 
LOG: after embedUnity 
LOG: load all.js started 
LOG: load all.js finished 
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'indexOf': object is null or undefined 
all.js, line 3 character 15
LOG: firstFrameCallback 
LOG: before send message[object HTMLObjectElement] uid undefined 
LOG: after send message`

Comment: There is an error thrown in all.js. (and all.js is by Facebook) It's not the first time I see this error. Is there a possibility to create a bug report?

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time something like this happens. You can file a report via https://developers.facebook.com/bugs. Please check if somebody already reported the problem. You might also find a work-around.

Comment: I'd wanted to test your app, but seems you haven't yet migrated to HTTPS as required by Facebook. It now throws the error `Secure browsing is not supported`. You should see Facebook's guide on [OAuth 2.0 and HTTPS Migration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/).

Comment: Thank you, Lachlan! Now the Application is migrated ...